# There's no row at posistion [0]

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, datarow

I have the following code:

```
private void ReturnForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string select = "SELECT TransactionID FROM [Transaction] WHERE ReturnDate = '" + null + "'";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TransactionID";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "TransactionID";
        comboBox1.DataSource = con.FillTable(select);
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int rentduration;
        int lateduration;
        double extracharge;
        int totalprice;
        int price;

        string a = "SELECT StaffID,CarID,ClientName,StartDate,EndDate FROM [Transaction] WHERE TransactionID = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
        string b = "SELECT * FROM MsCar WHERE CarrID = '" + label12.Text + "'";

        DataTable dt = con.FillTable(a);
        DataTable da = con.FillTable(b);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            label10.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            label11.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
            label12.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            label13.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
            label14.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
            label15.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM dd YYYY");
}
```

When I run the form, this code throws an error:

> There is no row at position 0.

But when I use the datagridview:

```
datagridview1.datasource = dt;
```

All the data is shown.

Please help me.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: try to trace your code by inserting a breakpoint at line : `DataTable dt = con.FillTable(a);` and see what will be filled in the first row of your datatable and what is inside `dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();`

Comment: and also continue your trace to find any event firing that maybe makes problems.

Comment: Did you write this code recently on your own? It seems the DataTable is not created correctly which means you have a table but only with title head name.

Comment: Can you also show your FillTable(string string) method?

Comment: @Kay lee : my FillTable method is on the another class, but i've  been resolved  this error sir, thanks you so much for your help sir

Comment: @AndreasGustaviano, You're also welcome, sir. Make good program !

Answer (score 1):

Try to use your combobox selection after it is committed combobox selected index change also occurs while closing the form and selected index change event function is used with empty strings. Also remove spaces while sending data to `SqlDataAdapter`.

Use

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

instead of

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and

```
 string a = "SELECT StaffID,CarID,ClientName,StartDate,EndDate FROM [Transaction] WHERE TransactionID = '" + comboBox1.Text.Trim() + "'";
```